# How get text between two closed tags Snoopy PHP

Tags: php, snoopy

How can i retrieve the text between two tags with Snoopy PHP 
Example :

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> Test </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

in this example i want get "Test"
thanks

Comment: you can use `strip_tags` function in php

Comment: as @BPRAM said `strip_tags('<html><body><h1> Test </h1><br></body></html>')`; should give you exactly 'Test'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this code it will give you the result**

```
<?php
 $doc =new DOMDocument();
 $doc->loadHTML("<html><body><h1>TEst</h1></body></html>");
 $xml=simplexml_import_dom($doc);
 $h1 = $xml->xpath('//h1');
 echo $h1[0];
?>
```